# Html header weird position on smartphones

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on my first responsive website, that I want to look good on a smartphone as well. My problem is that the picture/logo is placed below line, and title is placed above line (See the images below). How can this be done probably?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9qtu6ec/)

Html:

```
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <img src="Image link"/>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="navbar"> </div>
 </div 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
margin: 0;
background-color: #fff;
font-family: Verdana, Georgia, serif;
font-size: 14px;
overflow-x: hidden;
} 



.header {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #363636;
 height: 6em;
 text-align: left;
 font-size:150%;
 } 

 .header img {
 margin-left: 3em;  
 max-height: 4em;
 max-height: 4em;
 height:auto;
 display:inline;    

 position: relative;
 top: 25%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(+25%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(+25%);
 transform: translateY(+25%);
 }

.header h3{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: inline;
font-size: 250%;
text-align: left;
font-family: "Century Gothic";
margin: 0;
margin-left: 1em;
margin-top: 0;
position: relative;
top: -50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
min-width: 500px:
}

.header h3 a{
color: #fff;
}
```

What page currently look like on smartphone(HTC Desire HD: 480x800):

[image: What it looks like on smartphone(HTC Desire HD: 480x800)]

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

How it currently look on pc.

[image: How it looks on pc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS are a bit messy with all relatives, percentage offsets and translations (why this?). Simplest way to put elements next to each other are floats, but remember you have to clear after them. 
Here is some base you can build upon:

```
body,html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #363636;
    height: 6em;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:150%;
} 

.header:after {
    content:'';
    clear:both;
}

.header img {
    margin-left: 3em;   
    max-height: 4em;
    height:auto;
    display:block;  
    margin-top:1em;
    float:left;
}

.header h3 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 250%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Century Gothic",
   "Gill Sans", Arial, serif;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.7em;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, in Explore, Chrome and on my smartphone. That is the answer to my problems. I know my code is very messy, I've just tried different stuff, till it looked like i wanted, I need to go more in depth i think :)

Answer (score 0):

here i think it is what you want

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
} 



.header {
     margin: 0;
    background-color: #363636;
    height: auto; //changed
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 60px;  //changed
    padding-bottom: 1em; //changed
} 

.header img {
 margin-left: 3em; 
 max-height: 4em;
 max-height: 4em;
 height:auto;
 display:inline; 
 
 position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(+25%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(+25%);
  transform: translateY(+25%);
}

.header h3{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 250%;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: "Century Gothic",
   "Gill Sans", Arial, serif;
 margin: 0;
     margin-left: 1.2em; //changed
 margin-top: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: -50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 min-width: 500px:
}

.header h3 a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
   <img src="https://www.taskers.com/images/labels/500x500w/Natural%20Beige%20301%20(1500%20x%201500)-c44a470ba740c7e1e7bae946387be713.jpg"/>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="navbar"> </div>
  </div

 
      </body>
```

here i just updated your code to demo

[Check out demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x9qtu6ec/10/)

Comment: This is not answer and this is not responsive at all..neither in desktop or mobile..please check in ff and chrome too.

Comment: Just tested it, and look fine in browser, but on mobile device the image is moved halfway down the page.

Comment: @RasmusGP, your code is different view in chrome and firefox..check there.

Comment: @Leothelion Ohh I see what you mean. Just though I found a solution, that some guy commented, which simple was remove position: Relative; which fixed the problem, on the mobile device. If you test it on explore with that change, the image is placed correctly, but the text is still raised.

Comment: well that was me who commented on your post that remove position:relative but then i found its not working in firefox so i removed that